# Changing the input for a webscrape in a for loop (python 3)

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape three different websites using the same code over and over again.  Was wondering how I change the website input and the excel output using the three different sites.

So I would scrape each website in the list, and then export each result as follows in the order of the list: 1.) Sports.xlsx, Entertainment.xlsx,News.xlsx

```
websites ["https://news.google.com/news/section?topic=s","https://news.google.com/news/section?topic=e", "https://news.google.com/"

for x in websites:
     for wiki in wikis:
          website = requests.get(wiki)
          soup = BeautifulSoup(website.content, "lxml")
          text = ''.join([element.text for element in soup.body.find_all(lambda tag: tag != 'script', recursive=False)])
          new =  re.sub(r'[^a-zA-Z \n]','',text)

      import xlsxwriter
      if x == "https://news.google.com/news/section?topic=s"
             new.to_excel('sports.xlsx', index=False)
      elif x == "https://news.google.com/news/section?topic=e"
             new.to_excel('entertainment.xlsx', index=False)
      elif x == "https://news.google.com/"
             new.to_excel('news.xlsx', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just make your list a set of tuples of the following format:

```
websites = [ (link, file_object) ]

for link, file_object in websites: # Unpacks the tuple for each element in the list
    # open the link, then write in the website
```